# How to discover Spring Cloud Eureka Client memory leak cause?

Tags: java, spring, memory-leaks, netflix-eureka

I have a microservice written in Java with Spring-Cloud Eureka Client dependency.
When I undeploy it from Wildfly the Metaspace memory isn't released; investigating about the causes with Eclipse MAT, I realized that some threads of Eureka Client are alive generating ClassLoaders memory leak.

These are the strong references of one of these ClassLoaders:
[processing headdump in MAT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWDqg.png)

I use the following maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

with this version of Spring Cloud:

```
<spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
```

During the process of undeploying I read in the server log that the shutdown() function of the EurekaClient Bean terminate successfully. Any suggestions on how go deeper to realize the causes?